# Honda Civic 2010 (8th gen) won't start

Tags: engine, honda, civic

My 2010 civic will crank but won't start. All the normal dash lights will turn on however, the engine won't start. It will sometimes make a little sound but most of the time it stays silent. I tried leaving it be for about an hour and tried again but this time a small green key light turned on quickly before disappearing and the check engine light went on.

Anyone have suggestions as to what it may be?
PS: I used it the day before and it was working perfectly.

Comment: The green key means your coded key is not being read.  It will normally flash if its a real problem, so it could have just been a coincidence or temporary problem since it went right off.  If you have another key, try that, otherwise you need to read the codes from the check engine light.  That would tell you if an engine sensor or other component has failed (hopefully).

Comment: That sounds like normal operation to me. The security light should always illuminate and shut off after a second or so. The check engine light should always be on KOEO. You should check for codes like JPhi suggested.